# Teradata - Lag column and UNBOUNDED PRECEDING

Tags: sql, teradata, lag

suppose I have the following table in teradata sql.
How do I get the 'final' column.

The first value is equal to the 'mount' column, the second is equal to final - price (10-1), and the third is equal (9-2).

```
hour    mount   price
0       10       1
1       10       2
2       10       3 

hour    mount   price   final
0        10      1       10
1        10      2       9
2        10      3       7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a cumulative sum -- and then the difference from `mount`:

```
select hour, mount price,
       (mount + price -
        sum(price) over (order by hour rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
       ) as final
from t;
```

You really want the sum up to the preceding row.  But if you use:

```
        sum(price) over (order by hour rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
```

then you will need to deal with `NULL` values.  Instead, I just add `price` in from the current row and then let the cumulative sum include that price.